# Transitive property of linear dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

If $a$ and $b$ are linearly dependent, and $b$ and $c$ also linearly dependent, does it follow $a$ and $c$ are linearly dependent?

Comment: When you say "related linearly" do you mean, for example, that $a=\lambda b$ for some constant $\lambda$?

Comment: What is your definition of linearly related? You should be able to deduce it by just applying the definition. I'm assuming $a,b$ and $c$ are vectors, is that right?

Answer (score 3):

No, if $b=0$, $b$ is necessarily linearly related to $a$ and $c$ regardless of $a$ and $c$ being linearly related.

However if $b \ne 0$, there exist $\lambda, \mu \in \Bbb K$ (where $\Bbb K$ is your scalar field) such that $a = \lambda b$ and $c = \mu b$. Therefore, either $a=0$ or $a = {\mu \over\lambda}c$, and thus $a$ and $c$ are linearly related